# NGINX : How to configure mutual authentication for TCP Upstream?

Tags: nginx, ssl, tls

The particular feature I am interested about about SSL termination for TCP Upstream. I am evaluating both NGINX Open Source and NGINX Plus.

We have an application which accepts messages (TCP) over TLS from clients. With NGINX, I want to terminate TLS at NGINX and then NGINX will forward the decrypted packets to the application. Please note my application does NOT receive message over HTTP, but over TCP (Hence HTTP(S) related modules are not valid for my use case).

Client(s) --(TLS)--> NGINX --(Decrypted)--> Application

I have configured NGINX for TCP load balancing following [this](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/tcp-load-balancing/) document (Non-SSL). For that I have to build the source code with the following two modules:

1. ngx_stream_core_module
2. ngx_stream_ssl_module

Now, I want to enable mutual authentication with SSL between NGINX and the clients. I am seeing this [documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-tcp-ssl-termination/) which talks about server side authentication (client verifying server's certificate), but I am not able to find out the steps to configure mutual authentication (both client and server verifying each other's certificates). Could you please help me there? In the "ngx_stream_ssl_module" I don't find any option to mention client certificate.

Following is the content of my nginx.conf:

```
stream {
      server {
        listen *:5222 ssl;
        proxy_pass backend;
        ssl_certificate      /usr/local/nginx/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/nginx/certs/server.key;
        ssl_protocols         SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers           HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_session_cache     shared:SSL:20m;
        ssl_session_timeout   4h;
        ssl_handshake_timeout 30s;
      }

      upstream backend {
        server 0.0.0.0:5223;
      }
}
```

Also I want to allow (SSL handshake) only if client has a specific identity (may be based on the client's identifier/unique name). Is there any way to do it using NGINX or NGINX Plus?

Any other suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Start at http://nginx.org/r/ssl_trusted_certificate

Comment: Isn't it related to https? ssl_client_certificate is not valid for TCP Upstream. I have updated current nginx.conf

Comment: @ArnabBiswas did you ever find a solution

Comment: @ChristianMatthew No.

Comment: I found a solution. Did you want me to help you out? It's with nginx

Comment: are you getting this error? SSL Error:“unsupported certificate purpose”

Comment: Sorry. I posted this question 6 years back. I no longer work in this area.

Answer (score 4):

Looks Like the Module ngx_stream_ssl_module doesn't support these directive **ssl_client_certificate**,  **ssl_verify_client**

```
stream {
          server {
            listen *:5222 ssl;
            proxy_pass backend;
            ssl_certificate      /usr/local/nginx/certs/server.crt; # Can Include the Chain
            ssl_certificate_key  /usr/local/nginx/certs/server.key;
            ssl_protocols         TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Removed SSLv3
            ssl_ciphers           HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
            ssl_session_cache     shared:SSL:20m;
            ssl_session_timeout   4h;
            ssl_handshake_timeout 30s;

            ssl_client_certificate  /usr/local/nginx/certs/ca.chain.cert.pem;
            ssl_verify_client on;
            ssl_verify_depth 2;
          }

          upstream backend {
            server 0.0.0.0:5223;
          }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: "ssl_client_certificate" is part of the module "ngx_http_ssl_module" where as in my case, I had to enable "ngx_stream_ssl_module".

Comment: @ArnabBiswas Got the Point,

Comment: it's supported in 2019: http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_module.html also this might be helpful: https://gist.github.com/kekru/c09dbab5e78bf76402966b13fa72b9d2#terminating-tls-forward-tcp

Comment: @AlecIstomin is this the answer. I am trying to do a similar thing.

Answer (score 3):

```
 server {
    listen      80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ...

    location /upstream {
        proxy_pass                    https://backend.example.com;
        proxy_ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/client.pem;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/client.key
        proxy_ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        proxy_ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/trusted_ca_cert.crt;

        proxy_ssl_verify        on;
        proxy_ssl_verify_depth  2;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
    }
}
```

If you use a self-signed certificate, you should include the CA file : `proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate`.